# How to dynamically set field value in views?

Tags: django

I have a model, say 'Article', with a field

```
published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and a template with condition:

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
    <li>form.published.label_tag</li>
    <li>form.published</li>
{% else %}
    <li>form.published.as_hidden</li>
{% endif %}
```

and I use class-based generic views to add and update for this model.

In this case it is still possible for regular non-staff and malicious user to replace the value of `published` field.

I think I have to move the condition to views level to prevent this issue, somithing like

```
class ArticleEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.request.user.is_staff:

            ''' How to let the staff change this value? '''

        else:

            ''' How to set previous value? '''

        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

assuming that I remove this hidden field from template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider defining two forms, one for staff and one for regular users. You can then override the [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_class) method to select the correct form. If you exclude the `published` field from the form for non-staff, then they won't be able to change the value.

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ('published',)


class ArticleStaffForm(ArticleForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ()

class ArticleEdit(UpdateView):
    ...
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return ArticleStaffForm
        else:
            return ArticleForm
```

Comment: This code will set `published` to `False` even if it was `True` before editing. How do I overcome this? Thank you for having time to help.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. I think the problem might be in your template. Try rendering the form as `{{ form }}` and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not user.is_staff:
            del self.fields['published']
```

and then pass the request.user object to the form when initialising it.

WARNING: Untested pseudo code. But this should give you an idea.

Comment: This code only deletes the field from the form. This is not the case since I manually display every field, not via `{{ form.as_ul }}`. The question is how to implement this pseudo code:
`if (user.is_staff) { read user's input and save it } else { leave the value unchanged` }

Comment: To make this approach work, you'd have to do something like overriding `get_form_kwargs` to provide the `user` argument when initialising the form.

Comment: Ok, if I somehow pass `user` object to form and get to know if the user not `is_staff`, how do I set `published` field to its own value before editing (e.g. if it was `True` previously)?